# Trying to create an editable pdf with Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, pisa

I'm trying to create a PDF with checkboxes that can be checked (using python). I've been trying to use pisa to generate the pdf and have looked around the internet and tried different examples but I cannot find out how to make an editable PDF.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
import cStringIO
import ho.pisa as pisa
import os

# shortcut for dumping all logs on screen
pisa.showLogging()

def HTML2PDF(data, filename, open=False):
    """
        Simple test showing how to create a PDF file from
        PML Source String. Also shows errors and tries to start
        the resulting PDF
    """
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(cStringIO.StringIO(data), file(filename, "wb"))

    if open and not(pdf.err):
        os.startfile(str(filename))

    return not pdf.err

if __name__=="__main__":
    HTMLTEST = """
        <html>
            <body>
                <form name="deleteForm" method="get" action="">
                     User 1 <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="delete" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
   """

   HTML2PDF(HTMLTEST, "test.pdf", open=True)
```

The form gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/horeth/PycharmProjects/Reportlab/HTMLtoPF/Main.py", line 32, in 
      HTML2PDF(HTMLTEST, "test.pdf", open=True)
  File "C:/Users/horeth/PycharmProjects/Reportlab/HTMLtoPF/Main.py", line 14, in HTML2PDF
      pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(cStringIO.StringIO(data), file(filename, "wb"))
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.pdf'
```

The check boxes are for readers to decide if a user needs to be deleted or not.

I'm wondering if there is a way to create an editable PDF document with Python. This is just one of the attempts I've made so far, as an example.

Comment: For right now, I just want to make a PDF with just one user and one checkbox

Comment: it is trying to create the pdf in a location where you do not have permission to write to ... thats my guess from your error message

Comment: I do have permission to write to it. But what I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to create an editable PDF in Python.

Comment: the error you are getting is a permission error ... maybe the pdf is open in a program that is locking out changes (I think acrobat will not allow changes to files it has open)  It has nothing to do with the pdf content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons. You don't have write permission to the directory. The file already exists but you do not have write access to it.

Comment: I do have write permission, I tried the code above but with slightly different HTML inside it. My goal is to find a way to make an editable PDF with Python. I thought this way would work, and I've been trying a bunch of different things and none of them are working. I tried reportlab as well

Comment: you do not have permission to write ... whether thats because its trying to open it in a different directory than you think or the pdf is open in an application that will not allow changes to files while it has them open.  this has nothing to do with the content you are writing

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it created the pdf fine... that said ... it did not add the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
import cStringIO as StringIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from cgi import escape

def render_to_pdf(template_path, context_dict): 
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-
1")), dest=result)
    if not pdf.err: 
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), 
content_type='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % 
escape(html))
```

## Call this function

```
def myview(request):
    return render_to_pdf('HTMLTEST.html', { 'pagesize':'A4',})
```

## create a seperate html file

HTMLTEST.html

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <form name="deleteForm" method="get" action="">
                 User 1 <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="delete" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```